# Using manipulate to plot random points with sliding bar

Tags: manipulate

In the following code, I have tried to plot basically a distribution of points that I have assigned to be called Acoords and Bcoords. What I want is for the number of points to be a function of time. That is the sol1 and sol2 here (solutions to the differential equation, A[t] and B[t]). If I specify a particular t, the plot is exactly how I want it. However, when I try to add it to the manipulate function to plot the time dependence, it remain stagnant. I have tried to use the Evaluate function, but to no avail. My question is how I can implement time dependence properly so that the diagram evolves as I change the time using the slide bar? Any help would be greatly appreciated, and the code it pasted below!

```
A0 = 8; (*number of soldiers in force one*)

B0 = 6; (*number of soldiers in force two*)
\[Alpha] = 
  10.1; (*firepower of force force one*)
\[Beta] = 
  18; (*firepower of force force two*)

xbound = 20;(*size of battlefield*)
ybound = 20;(*size of battlefield*)

sol = DSolve[{A'[t] == -\[Beta]*B[t], B'[t] == -\[Alpha]*A [t], 
    A[0] == A0, B[0] == B0}, {A[t], B[t]}, t];

sol1 = A[t] /. sol[[1, 1]];
sol2 = B[t] /. sol[[1, 2]];

xcoordA = {};
ycoordA = {};
xcoordB = {};
ycoordB = {};

t = 0.005;

numbersoldiersA = Round[sol1];
numbersoldiersB = Round[sol2];
For[i = 0, i < numbersoldiersA, i++, 
  xcoordA = Append[xcoordA, RandomInteger[xbound]]];
For[j = 0, j < numbersoldiersA, j++, 
  ycoordA = Append[ycoordA, RandomInteger[xbound]]];
For[k = 0, k < numbersoldiersB, k++, 
  xcoordB = Append[xcoordB, RandomInteger[xbound]]];
For[l = 0, l < numbersoldiersB, l++, 
  ycoordB = Append[ycoordB, RandomInteger[xbound]]];

Acoords = Table[{xcoordA[[i]], ycoordA[[i]]}, {i, numbersoldiersA}];
Bcoords = Table[{xcoordB[[i]], ycoordB[[i]]}, {i, numbersoldiersB}];

listplot = 
  ListPlot[{Acoords, Bcoords}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
   PlotRange -> 21, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times", , Black, 
     Bold}, FrameLabel -> {\.00 \.00 "INSERT", "INSERT"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "INSERT", PlotStyle -> {Pink, Blue}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> {"INSERT", "INSERT"}];

Show[listplot]

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[{Evaluate[Acoords], Evaluate[Bcoords]}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotRange -> 21, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times", , Black, 
    Bold}, FrameLabel -> {\.00 \.00 "INSERT", "INSERT"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "INSERT", PlotStyle -> {Pink, Blue}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> {"INSERT", "INSERT"}], {t, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

These are currently the plots that I see:

[image]

Comment: The code you show does not run. Everything above Manipulate gives errors. I did not run your manipulate code. Only the code above it.   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZFVt.png)  Please make sure the code has no errors before using it in Manipulate

Comment: you have to plug in a t value, and then it doesnt give an error i believe. but this is exactly what i dont want to have to do. if you put t=0.005 in the parameter section, everything runs fine for me @Nasser are you saying it doesnt for you ?

Comment: **you have to plug in a t value** but I am just running the code you gave.

Comment: Look at Acoords, Bcoords, they do not have a form that can be used in a iterator statement

Comment: @DanielHuber could you elaborate on what you mean by this?

Comment: @Nasser sorry i am confused. i edited the code to set a t value. i have ran this in my own mathematica, and i confirmed again it works and generates a plot. im not sure why it's throwing up errors? i ran it in the exact order i have in the post (with the t value included below the coordinate definitions). i have added images of the plots.

Comment: Did you change your code? Now it runs without error. And Acoords, Bcoords have a valid form.

Comment: yes, i added the t value i was talking about. but this is the problem, i do not want to specify a t. i want the slider to set the t and to plot according to that t. the issue is i just get this plot at one t instead of it being a dynamic variable. @DanielHuber

Comment: I think you have a problem with the localization of "t". For all parts outside of "Manipulate" that use "t", try to formulate it like a function of "t".

Comment: it doesnt let me set xcoordA = {}; as a function of t. i did everything else, but now it plots nothing. @DanielHuber

Comment: You plot A/Bcoords. These depend on x/ycoordA/B.  However, x/ycoordA/B do not depend on t. They consist of random integers.

Comment: but the number of coordinates depends on t @DanielHuber

Comment: I must have used your original code before you made some edits. No problem.

Comment: A/B[t] depend on t. However, by setting t=0.005; you are removing this dependence. What you need to do is to define e.g.: A[t_]= A[t]/. sol[[1, 1]]

Comment: defining A and B like that nothing changes unfortunately. if i try to define as a function anything past that, for instance, numbersoldiersB, it says that the symbol is protected, so i cannot. thus, the same issue still persists. @DanielHuber

Comment: Another possible issue: Do not use capitalized variable names, they are used by the system. Start with a new kernel, then "numbersoldiers" is certainly not proteced. Otherwise you need to show what you exactly do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to nest the calculations inside the Manipulate in order to update the results when you change time. And second, you should not use the same symbol t as a variable in `DSolve` and as a numerical value. In the following I use `tt` instead of `t` inside `Manipulate` and then a replacement rule to give numerical values to `sol1` and `sol2`. The code below works, by which I mean that the `ListPlot` changes when you slide the bar. Whether it does what you want it to do is another issue.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
A0 = 8; (*number of soldiers in force one*)

B0 = 6; (*number of soldiers in force two*)
\[Alpha] = 10.1; (*firepower of force force one*)
\[Beta] = 18; (*firepower of force force two*)

xbound = 20;(*size of battlefield*)
ybound = 20;(*size of battlefield*)

sol = DSolve[{A'[t] == -\[Beta]*B[t], B'[t] == -\[Alpha]*A[t], 
    A[0] == A0, B[0] == B0}, {A[t], B[t]}, t];

sol1 = A[t] /. sol[[1, 1]];
sol2 = B[t] /. sol[[1, 2]];

xcoordA = {};
ycoordA = {};
xcoordB = {};
ycoordB = {};

Manipulate[
 numbersoldiersA = Round[sol1 /. t -> tt];
 numbersoldiersB = Round[sol2 /. t -> tt];
 For[i = 0, i < numbersoldiersA, i++, 
  xcoordA = Append[xcoordA, RandomInteger[xbound]]];
 For[j = 0, j < numbersoldiersA, j++, 
  ycoordA = Append[ycoordA, RandomInteger[xbound]]];
 For[k = 0, k < numbersoldiersB, k++, 
  xcoordB = Append[xcoordB, RandomInteger[xbound]]];
 For[l = 0, l < numbersoldiersB, l++, 
  ycoordB = Append[ycoordB, RandomInteger[xbound]]];
 
 Acoords = Table[{xcoordA[[i]], ycoordA[[i]]}, {i, numbersoldiersA}];
 Bcoords = Table[{xcoordB[[i]], ycoordB[[i]]}, {i, numbersoldiersB}];
 
 listplot = 
  ListPlot[{Acoords, Bcoords}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
   PlotRange -> 21, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times", , Black, 
     Bold}, FrameLabel -> {\.00 \.00 "INSERT", "INSERT"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "INSERT", PlotStyle -> {Pink, Blue}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> {"INSERT", "INSERT"}]
 ,
 {tt, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: thank you very much, this does work perfectly. however, i am still confused about the replacement variable t->tt. I dont fully understand why it can't interpret t as the dynamic variable as well? could you elaborate on that?

Comment: In `DSolve` t is a dummy variable that tells DSolve which is the independent variable in the differential equation. The first time you run the code everything is fine but once you give t a value your definition of sol1 and sol2 breaks down. If you set t=0.1, for example, sol becomes 

    DSolve[{Derivative[1][A][0.1] == -18 B[0.1], 
      Derivative[1][B][0.1] == -10.1 A[0.1], A[0] == 8, 
      B[0] == 6}, {A[0.1], B[0.1]}, 0.1]

and you get the error message '0.1 cannot be used as a variable'.